# "Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception"

Tags: jdbc, driver

I create webpage using JSP and my server is Tomcat v7. My error as bellow:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class because of underlying exception: 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3306dbname"'.
```

I try to do it but still not.
Please help me with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like the configuration is wrong (extra information is tacked onto the port, perhaps?)

Comment: It tried to recognize `3306dbname` as a number, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Write

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname");
```

Instead of

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306dbname");
```